# Add image tooltip to Geometry nodes / Modifier UI?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes, interface

I'm currently trying to make a template file for a hat I've made using geometry nodes.

My issue is that although I have all my group input parameters neatly setup in the modifier tab - It will be quite difficult for someone else to come in and use it without having any visual reference for what they are adjusting...

(i.e. the integer values which are cycling through different objects within collections: stitching, buttons, zippers etc.)

[image]

Ideally I'm hoping to add in some kind of image tooltip to act as a visual reference within the UI like above (currently I'm just using the written tooltip to provide a written explanation of each of the objects which I find isn't very helpful)

I've mocked-up a screenshot below to hopefully explain my intended outcome, would something like this be possible in any way? with python maybe?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!